# TargetAuthenticationStrategy, change order of preference

Tags: java, apache, authentication, apache-httpclient-4.x

Apache 4.3.x logs the following authentication schemes in the order of preference:

```
[negotiate, Kerberos, NTLM, Digest, Basic]
```

How can I change this order?

I have tried the following:

```
 DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(ccm, params);
 // Choose BASIC over DIGEST for proxy authentication
 List<String> authpref = new ArrayList<String>();
 authpref.add(AuthPolicy.BASIC);
 authpref.add(AuthPolicy.DIGEST);
 httpclient.getParams().setParameter(AuthPNames.PROXY_AUTH_PREF, authpref);
```

But this is deprecated in 4.3.X, so maybe a better question is how to do the above in 4.3.x?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That should be roughly equivalent

```
RequestConfig config = RequestConfig.custom()
        .setProxyPreferredAuthSchemes(Arrays.asList(AuthSchemes.BASIC, AuthSchemes.DIGEST))
        .build();
CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.custom()
        .setDefaultRequestConfig(config)
        .build();
```